# Jquery name space functional process is not understandable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searching across the web about the `jquery.namespace` process. finally i got a answer in the stack overflow with this example script..

```
jQuery.namespace = function() {

    var a=arguments, o=null, i, j, d;

    for (i=0; i<a.length; i=i+1) {

        d=a[i].split(".");



        o=window;

        for (j=0; j<d.length; j=j+1) {

            o[d[j]]=o[d[j]] || {};
            o=o[d[j]];

             console.log(o); 
        }

    }
   // console.log(o); //Object {} 
    return o;
};

// definition
jQuery.namespace( 'jQuery.debug' );
jQuery.debug.test1 = function()
{
    alert( 'test1 function' );
};
jQuery.debug.test2 = function()
{
    alert( 'test2 function' );
};
// usage
jQuery.debug.test1();
jQuery.debug.test2();
```

It has 2 parts, once is "Jquery.namespace" - function and another is declaring new methods to name space. But i unable to understand what is "Jquery.namespace" function exactly do here.. i tried to understand line by line, but i couldn't get the process what the function do here..

Any one explain me about the function, about how that's works? or any other easy method to make name spacing using jQuery..

Thanks in advance

Comment: `jQuery.namespace( 'jQuery.debug' );` will reuse ‘jQuery.debug` Namespace if it exists, and create it if it doesn’t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is taking arguments which are a list of namespaces you want created.

lets simplify it so it only takes one namespace

```
jQuery.namespace = function(namespace) {
    var o=null, j, d;
    d=namespace.split(".");
    o=window;
    for (j=0; j<d.length; j=j+1) {
            o[d[j]]=o[d[j]] || {};
            o=o[d[j]]; 
        }
    }
    return o;
};
```

The function is then fairly simple. What is actually happening is starting from the window we are recursively checking if the objects we have declared in our namespace exist. For example take the call `jQuery.namespace('foo.bar')` the function would check to see if the window had an attribute `foo` and if not it would create it. The function would then check if `window.foo` had an attribute `bar` and if not create it.

In the end all the function does is create an object linked to the window (a global variable) which has all the relevant sub-objects. You are then just assigning functions and variables to the nested object rather than directly to the window which you would otherwise do with global variables.